# ExtJs4 Locked Column

Tags: extjs4

I am having a grid with 16columns. I want the following scenario -

I want first 5 columns and the last column to be locked. I can do this using locked:true.

But this brings the last column to the left hand side of the grid along with the first 5 columns.

Can i have the last column to its original position i.e. at the last and make first 5 and last column as locked.

I am using ExtJs-4.0.7

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - no. In ExtJs locked portion of the grid will be on left side.